# Is there any way to use es6 import and export features with grunt without using webpack

Tags: javascript, gruntjs, ecmascript-6, es6-module-loader

> I want to use es6 import and export featues with grunt setup, but i
>   don't want to use webpack to use import and export,
>
> **so Is there any way to use es6 import and export with grunt without using webpack ???**

My grunt-babel definition is:

```
babel: {
options: {
    sourceMap: true,
    presets: ['es2015']
},
build: {
    files: [{
        expand: true, // Enable dynamic expansion
        cwd: 'src/jass',
        src: ['**/*.js'], // Actual patterns to match
        dest: 'src/j'
    }]
}
}
```

I have uploaded the problem statement on Github, kindly [refer it](https://github.com/saeed3e/es6-import-export-with-grunt)

So when i run index.html, got the error "define is not defined"
[image]

Answer (score 0):

You might want to read about `babel-cli` which can do what you want, or if your primary focus is to get `import` and `export` working, you can use `babel-node`.

Consider reading this: https://babeljs.io/docs/usage/cli/

Comment: Yes my primary focus is how to use import and export using grunt setup. bcz after complie my code using babel and run the same code in browser, it throws an error. "import or export is not defined". so have i missed out any loader plugin, which i have to specify in grunt config.